# Stubhub http request

Tags: api, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to figure out how to use the HTTP request URL's provided by the stubhub Listing Catalog Service request page here: http://stubhubapi.stubhub.com/index.php/Anatomy_of_a_Listing_Catalog_Service_HTTP_Request

I looked at the example at the sample HTTP request, why does this: http://www.stubhub.com/listingCatalog/select/?q=%2B+stubhubDocumentType%3Agenre%0D%0A%2B+leaf%3Atrue%0D%0A&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on  return what it returns?

How to I modify this link to return only, say, Yankees game at Fenwick park?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Stubhub API Reference](http://stubhubapi.stubhub.com/index.php/Anatomy_of_a_Listing_Catalog_Service_HTTP_Request), the sample url:

http://www.stubhub.com/listingCatalog/select/?q=%2B+stubhubDocumentType%3Agenre%0D%0A%2B+leaf%3Atrue%0D%0A&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

is the following SOLR search query, converted to a URL query string:

> +stubhubDocumentType:genre
>
> +leaf:true

This actually looks more like

> +stubhubDocumentType:genre\n+leaf:true

and finally encoded to URL query

> %2B+stubhubDocumentType%3Agenre%0D%0A%2B+leaf%3Atrue%0D%0A

http://www.stubhub.com/listingCatalog/select/ is the endpoint

the parameters on the end specify options

For Yankees at Fenwick park, you would probably want to search for [Stubhub Events](http://stubhubapi.stubhub.com/index.php/Event_Index_Document) that are located in Fenwick park and have New York Yankees  in the description.

You should take a look at this [PHP example](http://stubhubapi.stubhub.com/index.php/PHP_Code_Sampleshttp://stubhubapi.stubhub.com/index.php/PHP_Code_Samples), which contains how to search the search for a specific search query.

For easy access to the Stubhub Api, check out a [Ruby Gem](https://github.com/rloomba/stubhub) that is a good wrapper for the API.